# ruby unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting '}'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I am learning ruby and I have problem in ruby 1.9.3 the error is

> unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting '}'

I attached my code in here [bot_data_to_yaml](https://gist.github.com/4151926)

I hope someone can give me answer what happen with my code, cause I am new in programming language.. thanks all

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're missing a comma, bracket, or brace somewhere.  Try a comma after:

```
 :farewell => ["Good bye!"]
```

Comment: hello, I already put comma after, but it still error.. I cofused.